# Approach to sending email reminders to users - process

Tags: php

I have built a task management system. I want to send an email to users that have an outstanding task that's over a certain time old, as a reminder.

What's the best approach doing this via a php script:

A) query the database and get relavant user emails, pop them into an array and then send emails

B) query database and at the point of finding a relavant user send the email immediately and then continue loop

I'm assuming mixing the querying with the sending of emails is probably not a good idea, and would be best to split the two processes?

Comment: I would recommend getting a list of the users first and then send the emails. If you have _many_ users, you can also fetch them in batches (like pagination).

Comment: Two CronJobs: 1 - generate queue of email data to send; 2 - Send emails from queue.